# Link to is behaving in different manner in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[image]

`props.repo.html-url` is returning `https://github.com/mojombo/docz-website`

Problem is when I click on link it goes to this URL: `http://localhost:3000/user/https://github.com/mojombo/docz-website`

I want to redirect to first URL, why it is behaving like this?

Comment: Because it's expecting to link to a *route*; if you already have the whole URL, just use an `a`nchor element. Also **do not** post screenshots of code, post *text*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for the answer so it's kind of link to a route that means it will always add to root '/' path, am I making sense?
And why shouldn't I use the screenshot? New to StackOverflow and learning so...

Comment: Yes, the Link is just for routes within your site and will add the root path. And because they aren't searchable, editable or accessible like text is.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple anchor tag in this case, as you are linking an external page and not a route defined whitin your application.

```
<a href={props.repo.html-url} rel="external">
     {props.repo.name}
</a>
```